# TinyMCE some buttons are not showing up

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to add a link/unlink and image button to my TinyMCE editor. Now I have the following code:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar1: 'link unlink image',
  toolbar2: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright'
});
```

However its showing an empty first toolbar. Please see my fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yofwte55/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used two toolbars though the issue seems to be with plugins, try instead using below:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link image',

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/yofwte55/3/)

Comment: Using two toolbars is actually valid, but I was missing the plug-in to show the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add needed plugins:

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
      toolbar1: 'link unlink image',
      toolbar2: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright',
      plugins: ["link image"],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Default icons are required to be imported in TinyMCE 5.3 or above.

```
import 'tinymce/icons/default';
```

Here are the references:

- TinyMCE Official Doc https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/